# How to get JSON response from Internet Explorer using COM object?

Tags: c++, json, internet-explorer, com

I'm trying to process JSON in a response from my localserver using a COM object in C++, but every time I try it the download window pops up. Is there anyway, apart from creating a new key entry in the Registry, to handle JSON without downloading it?

```cpp
...
BSTR bstrUrl = SysAllocString(L"http://localhost:5000/");
Var.vt = VT_I4;
Var.lVal = 0;
Browser->Navigate(bstrUrl, &Var, &Var, &VariantPostData, &VariantHeaders);
SysFreeString(bstrUrl);
do
{
    Sleep(1);
    Browser->get_Busy(&Busy);
} while (Busy);

Browser->get_Document(&Dispatch);
Dispatch->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (LPVOID *)&HTML);
Dispatch->Release();

HTML->get_body(&Element);
Element->get_innerHTML(&TestString);
std::wcout << TestString << std::endl;
```

The local server is returning something like this

```
{"login":succes,"authCode":"asdasdasd"}
```

Comment: Use an HTTP library to download the JSON instead of using a visual web browser. For instance, use Microsoft's WinInet API, see [HTTP Sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wininet/http-sessions) and in particular [Downloading Resources from the WWW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wininet/http-sessions#downloading-resources-from-the-www)

Comment: IE doesn't support displaying JSON content directly. To make IE display the JSON content instead of downloading it, you can change the response's Content-Type to text/plain, so IE will treat the response as plain text. But note by doing this, certain application scenarios may be broken. For example, sometimes the client expect the Content-Type to be appliction/json. Ref: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/12698f9a-ba89-410e-8192-f858f66fa484/how-to-tell-to-internet-explorer-to-show-a-json-object-response-from-a-server-rest-instead-to-try-to?forum=wcf